# Word for outdoor area on the side of a ship

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for the narrow uncovered walkway that fringes the sides of a ship? It's enclosed by a *railing*. I wouldn't call it a *deck*, because *deck* implies a larger open area. It's a passageway from the bow to the stern, or between different decks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question fits the description of **promenade deck** from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promenade_deck):

> The promenade deck is a deck found on several types of passenger ships and riverboats. It usually extends from bow to stern, on both sides, and includes areas open to the outside, resulting in a continuous outside walkway suitable for promenading, (ie, walking) thus the name.

A deck does not have to be a large open area:

> [**Deck**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deck) **1.** *Nautical* 
>   **a.** a floorlike surface wholly or partially occupying one level of a hull, superstructure, or deckhouse, generally cambered, and often serving as a member for strengthening the structure of a vessel.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean, "promenade deck"?